# How to use grep or awk to get particular numbers from a file and put them in a text file?

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have the following file "file.log" :

```
ABC : 1
XYZ : 10
MMM : 3

ABC : 4
XYZ : 22
MMM : 5

ABC : 22
XYZ : 1
MMM : 3

... and so on
```

I am trying to write a bash script that will check each of the lines with ABC and MMM (don't need XYZ) and only grab the integers ( e.g. 1, 4 and 22 for ABC and 3,5 and 3 for MMM) and put them all in a txt file , say, solution.txt.

I am using the following command :

```
cat file.log | grep "ABC" | grep -o '[0-9]\+' > solution.txt
```

But this only prints out the integers for ABC in order i.e

```
1
4
22
```

However I want them to be ABC followed by MMM in order as it appears in "file.log"

desired output :

```
1
3
4
5
22
3
```

Do I need to put grep in a loop to go only by one line after the other or if it can be combined with "awk" the problem can be solved ?

Thanks.

Comment: I would grep to filter them then use cut to get the number out. Sure you can use awk to get directly what you want, but the syntax is beyond my head

Comment: @BingWang could you please show by an example, when i try to filter using grep the integers for ABC and MMM are not in the sequence I want. All ABCs are together and same goes for MMM.

Comment: grep -E "^ABC|^XYZ" file.log which purifies the result a little bit. most modern (GNU) grep should work

Comment: last digit should be 3.

Comment: @BingWang awk syntax is a tiny subset of C, with a couple of extras to do common operations used when manipulating text. If you think it's beyond you then you're over-thinking it.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '/^(ABC|MMM) /{print $NF}' file
1
3
4
5
22
3
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F' *: *' '$1=="ABC" || $1=="MMM" {print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*' '/^(ABC +|MMM +)/{print $2}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Bing Wang's solution and was able to solve it

```
cat file-log | grep -E "^ABC|^XYZ" | grep -v "ABC|XYZ" | grep -o '[0-9]\+' > result.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing answer which you are using. IMHO honestly you need not to use these many commands for this one, you could do this in a single `awk` or so, you could check karafka, mine answer which will do the trick for you(why not doing this with so many commands is not good, single command will be easy to manage, should be faster than using multiple commands(ideal scenario)), cheers.

Comment: Don't do that. It's lengthy, buggy, inefficient, and non-portable.

Comment: Thanks. I just started working with bash, will definitely follow your advice